# Backing up open source gems in case they go away

Tags: ruby, git, rubygems

We are wondering how developers deal with the possibility that a gem author deletes the git repository and the gem goes away. Forking/Cloning every gem we use and updating them with every new version of our app starts to get ridiculous if we have hundreds of gem dependencies. How have other developers tackled this potential issue?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to fork the repo. You just have to clone it. You can always push your clone to a newly-created project later on, if needed.

But yes, this sort of thing has happened before, with all of [why the lucky stiff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Why_the_lucky_stiff)'s projects.

Answer (score 0):

The strategy is to stick to the majority. Only use gems that are very popular. The more popular, the less trouble. In case something happens, it is very likely that someone else using the same gem will do something for it.

Have you ever worried that Ruby itself gets abandoned? Have you ever worried that all operating systems die out? Have you ever worried that computers will become extinct? Have you ever worried that electricity supply will become deprecated?